# Has Daredevil ever lost his faith?

Tags: marvel, daredevil

I just caught up with season 3 of Daredevil, which follows Matt during a rather dark time in his life. As is traditional for characters of a religious bent, the arc included plenty of angst and arguments around his Catholic beliefs.

Viewing from a non-religious perspective, this led to a lot of weird cognitive dissonance in the storytelling (reasonable issues framed as petulant gripes, "losing faith" being used as "angry at God" and "not believing in God's existence" interchangeably) and it got me wondering - **has Daredevil ever stopped believing in the Christian God**?

(Note that I mean actually stopped believing, not simply a period of him being "mad at God" or "disagreeing with God", but one in which he examines his faith and decides he doesn't have enough evidence for belief)

Comment: I don't have time today to read through it, but http://www.adherents.com/lit/comics/Daredevil.html might be useful as a reference.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots some interesting reading there, but no answers. If anything, most were complaining that Daredevil isn't Catholic enough :P

Comment: There is this story arc [Guardian Devil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guardian_Devil) that was referenced in a couple sites as DD losing his faith, and the summary states "his faith renewed", but not familiar enough with that arc to state definitively. [Second site mentioning this](https://nothingbutcomics.net/2015/04/17/daredevil-guardian-devil/)